# Keras optimizer.get_updates(), K.function()のパラメータで[]は何ですか？

Tags: python, keras

```
    def critic_optimizer(self):
        #placeholder for target???
        disc_reward = K.placeholder(shape=(None,1))
        #output of critic
        value = self.critic.output
        #MSE error
        loss = K.mean(K.square(disc_reward - value))

        optimizer = Adam(lr=self.critic_lr)
        #what is the second [] parameter???
        updates = optimizer.get_updates(self.critic.trainable_weights, [], loss)
        #[] is an empty list for outputs?  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/function
        train = K.function([self.critic.input, disc_reward], [], updates=updates)
        return train
```

上記はA2CをKerasにて書いた例ですが、パラメータの[]が何か分かりません。

以下のメソッドでコールされてます。

```
def train_model(self, state, action, target, advantages):

        self.actor.optimizer([state, action, advantages])

        self.critic.optimizer([state, target])
```

ソースはこちらです：[ソース](https://github.com/Hyeokreal/Actor-Critic-Continuous-Keras/blob/master/a2c_continuous.py)

Keras及びTensorflowのドキュメンテーションを読んでも、メソッドのパラメータが全部載っていませんでしたが、メソッドのパラメーターが載っている書籍がありましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://keras.io/backend/#function

このFunctionには「出力がない」という意味ではないでしょうか。

---

Tensorflowバックエンドの実装が
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2724
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2509
このあたりです。

`outputs`に`[]`を指定すると、ここ
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2676

```
    return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
```

に効いてきて、長さ0のリストが返ります。

「出力がない」という指定なので出力を見る必要はなく、実際質問のコードでも

```
    self.critic.optimizer([state, target])
```

として結果を**捨てて**います。

Comment: なるほどですね。実際にライブラリーのソースをトレースすること、勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

回答になっていない気がしますが、
helpだと、以下のように見えます。
この領域、初心者につき、情報が間違えているかもしれません。

```
>>> from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop, SGD, Adam
>>> help(Adam)
Help on class Adam in module tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam:

class Adam(tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2)
 |  Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False, name='Adam', **kwargs)
 |

...
 |
 |  get_updates(self, loss, params)
 |
```

バージョンでインターフェースが変更され、それの置き換えがデコレータで実施されているようです。

```
def get_updates_arg_preprocessing(args, kwargs): 
# Old interface: (params, constraints, loss) 
# New interface: (loss, params) 
if len(args) > 4:
...
```

という置き換えです。よって、[ ]は、constraintsで制約のようですが、不要のようです。

Comment: この場合、`params`ではなさそうですよね。`loss`も最後に並んでいますし、`loss=loss`での表記でもありませんし、どうなんでしょうか。

Comment: バージョンでインターフェースが変更され、それの置き換えがデコレータで実施されているようです。def get_updates_arg_preprocessing(args, kwargs):
    # Old interface: (params, constraints, loss)
    # New interface: (loss, params)
    if len(args) > 4:という置き換えです。よって、[ ]は、constraintsで制約のようですが、不要のようです。